# How does Pandas calculate the covariance matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have just jumped into doing stats/machine learning using python and I had been calculating covariance matrices using linear algebra.

For example:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as pre
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'classification']
iris = pd.read_csv('data/iris.data', names=cols)
data = iris.loc[:,'sepal length':'petal width']
centered = pd.DataFrame(pre.scale(data, with_std=False), columns=iris.columns[0:4])
cov = centered.T @ centered
```

Then, I noticed that the DataFrame object has a method to calculate the covariance matrix, but that it gives me a different set of values.

```
cov = centered.cov()
```

I was wondering why this is happening. I'm guessing it is some sort of scaling of the data, but I'm new to statistics and not really sure. It makes me wonder if I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Have you done any research, checked the documentation?

Comment: My question has been answered already, but yes, I did check the documentation first. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html)

> Returns the covariance matrix of the DataFrame’s time series. **The
>   covariance is normalized by N-1.**

Comment: I'm not sure what that scaling means conceptually, but multiplying by 1/n-1 did give me the same results.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166568/why-do-we-divide-by-n-1-when-calculating-sample-correlation